# How can I use a sys excepthook and then continue the code from a loop after the error message?

Tags: python, error-handling, sys

I am trying to create an average solver which can take a tuple and average the numbers. I want to use the except hook to give an error message and then continue from the beginning of the while loop. 'continue' does not work.

```
import sys
z = 1
x = []
y = 1
i = 1
print('Welcome to the Average Solver.')
while z==1 :
    def my_except_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
        print('Please only use integers.')
        continue
    sys.excepthook = my_except_hook
    print("Enter your set with commas between numbers.")
    x=input()
    i=len(x)
    print('The number of numbers is:',i)
    y=float(float(sum(x))/i)
    print('Your average is', float(y))
    print(' ')
    print("Would you like to quit? Press 0 to quit, press 1 to continue.")
    z=input()
print('Thank you for your time.')
```

Comment: `continue` is in the body of `my_except_hook`, it doesn't "know" about the `while` loop.  You should define all classes, functions, etc. only once, outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I solved the problem. I just used a try-except clause...

```
z = 1
x = []
y = 1
i = 1
print('Welcome to the Average Solver.')

while z == 1:
    try:
        print("Enter your set with commas between numbers.")
        x = input()
        i = len(x)
        y = float(float(sum(x)) / i)
        print('Your average is', float(y))
        print(' ')
        print("Would you like to quit? Press 0 to quit, press 1 to continue.")
        z = input()
    except:
        print('Please use integers.')
        x = []
        continue


print('Thank you for your time.')
```

Answer (score 0):

As @PatrickHaugh noted, the keyword `continue` means nothing to `my_except_hook`. It is only relevant inside a `while` loop. I know this is what you are trying to do by having `continue` being called in the *flow* of a loop, but it's not really in the **context** of a loop, so it doesn't work.

---

Also, `i` is how many numbers you are, yet you set it as the length of the user input. However, this will include commas! If you want the *real* amount of numbers, set `i = len (x.split (","))`. This will find out how many numbers are in between the commas.

Comment: But when I test my code, it still returns the correct average. I think it is because I set x as a tuple.